# R cumulative bind.rows

Tags: r, bind

I would like to find away to bind.rows cumulatively. Here is small example, what I would like to achieve. I will demo with gapminder dataset from `dslabs` package.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)

gapminder %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  head(5)

A tibble: 5 x 2
   year data              
  <int> <list>            
1  1960 <tibble [185 x 8]>
2  1961 <tibble [185 x 8]>
3  1962 <tibble [185 x 8]>
4  1963 <tibble [185 x 8]>
5  1964 <tibble [185 x 8]>
```

I would like to create column, which would bind earlier observations from data column together. So for example row 1 only would have year 1960 data, row 2 would have 1960 + 1961 data, row 3 1960 + 1961 + 1963 data... End result should look something like this.

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
   year data               cumulative_data   
  <int> <list>             <list>            
1  1960 <tibble [185 x 8]> <tibble [185 x 8]>
2  1961 <tibble [185 x 8]> <tibble [370 x 8]>
3  1962 <tibble [185 x 8]> <tibble [555 x 8]>
4  1963 <tibble [185 x 8]> <tibble [740 x 8]>
5  1964 <tibble [185 x 8]> <tibble [925 x 8]>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Reduce` with the `accumulate = TRUE` option allows to achieve that:

```
gapminder %>%
  group_by(year) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  head(5) %>%
  mutate(cumulative_data = Reduce(rbind, data, accumulate = TRUE))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#    year data               cumulative_data   
#   <int> <list>             <list>            
# 1  1960 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [185 × 8]>
# 2  1961 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [370 × 8]>
# 3  1962 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [555 × 8]>
# 4  1963 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [740 × 8]>
# 5  1964 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [925 × 8]>
```

Answer (score 2):

In `tidyverse`, we can also make use of `accumulate` from `purrr`

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dslabs)
gapminder %>%
   group_by(year) %>% 
   nest() %>% 
   head(5) %>%
   mutate(cumulative_data = accumulate(data, bind_rows)) 
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#   year data               cumulative_data   
#  <int> <list>             <list>            
#1  1960 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [185 × 8]>
#2  1961 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [370 × 8]>
#3  1962 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [555 × 8]>
#4  1963 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [740 × 8]>
#5  1964 <tibble [185 × 8]> <tibble [925 × 8]>
```